# CSS for table column overflow into next column

Tags: css

I'm fairly new to coding and I just can't figure out to make the text in one row of a column to wrap. Right now they overflow into the next column. The table is responsive, but this one line refuses to cooperate. I do not have access to the html so it has to be fixed with just css.

I've tried overflow, text-overflow, white-space, overflow-wrap, nothing works!

I know I'm targeting the right div and class since i'm able to make that exact text red, but when I try to make the words wrap, in Chrome Dev Tools, it automatically gets a strikethrough.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#IDX-showcaseGallery-3643.IDX-showcaseTable .IDX-showcaseCityStateZip  span.IDX-showcaseAddressElement {
 overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
 color: red;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: Example]

The website is newtraditionrealty.com .

Thanks for an advice!

Comment: From what I can tell, without seeing code, it looks as though you don't have white space in between your text where it needs to wrap.
`vancouver,washington` vs `vancouver, washington`.

Comment: add this `.IDX-showcaseCityStateZip span {
    white-space: normal!important;
}`

Comment: You darling! It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This rule is preventing your white space from wrapping:

```
.IDX-showcaseCityStateZip span {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Removing it allows the text to wrap again.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: I removed it and did the suggestion above and it's wrapping. Thank you guys!

Comment: Don't forget to accept or up vote answers you found useful